# Python: simple mapping of dataframe styler

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styling

I am stuck on figuring out how to map a pre-existing df of styling options to a df of integers:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a 9 x 3 array of integers
random_state = np.random.RandomState(seed=44)
myArray = random_state.randint(0,9, (9,3))
```

Which gives the output:

```
[[4 3 1]
 [3 0 4]
 [3 8 7]
 [7 6 3]
 [7 3 3]
 [6 5 4]
 [5 1 8]
 [7 4 5]
 [3 0 4]]
```

Then create a random 2D list of 'color: option' to be mapped onto myArray with the styler:

```
styleList    = []
colorOptions = ['color: lime','color: red','color: yellow']

for i in arr:
  inner = []
  for j in i:
    inner.append(np.random.choice(colorOptions))
  styleList.append(inner)

for i in styleList: print(i)
```

Check the output:

```
['color: yellow', 'color: lime'  , 'color: red']
['color: red'   , 'color: lime'  , 'color: red']
['color: yellow', 'color: yellow', 'color: yellow']
['color: yellow', 'color: red'   , 'color: lime']
['color: yellow', 'color: red'   , 'color: yellow']
['color: red'   , 'color: lime'  , 'color: yellow']
['color: red'   , 'color: yellow', 'color: red']
['color: yellow', 'color: yellow', 'color: yellow']
['color: lime'  , 'color: red'   , 'color: red']
```

Convert both of these to dataframes:

```
df      = pd.DataFrame(data=myArray,   index=None, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
dfStyle = pd.DataFrame(data=styleList, index=None, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Since I already have the dataframe `dfStyle` with the styling options, **how can I simply map its values to the integer values in `df`** (and without having to generate `dfStyle` within a separate function)?

I'll avoid cluttering this space with my various attempts using `df.style.apply()`, `df.style.applymap()` and even functions that attempt to simply return `dfStyle`, but this seemingly straightforward task has thrown me in circles.

Desired result is a styled df:

**`df[0][0]`** should be the number 4 displayed with the color yellow

**`df[0][1]`** should be the number 3 displayed with the color lime

**`df[0][2]`** should be the number 1 displayed with the color red

etc.

Thanks for any help.

**••• UPDATE •••**

I figured out how to properly map the style as I wanted by using:

```
def color(row):
  dfs = dfStyle.copy()
  x = [dfs.iloc[row.name][j] for i,j in zip(row, dfStyle)]
  return x

df.style.apply(color, axis=1)
```

which results in the desired:

[image]

Comment: The only place you define dfStyle is in the statement ```dfStyle = pd.DataFrame(data=styleList, index=None, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])''' , you probably don't need to define df.  I am not sure what you believe is your problem.

Comment: Even if it is not necessary to convert `styleList` into a dataframe, could you please provide the code showing how to map the color options directly onto the values of `df`?

Comment: I don't understand your mapping.  From what I can gather you are creating a list of three randomly selected values from color_options, for each row of the myArray, the contents of myArray are never used.  What mapping are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Don't post the desired result in the comments, go back edit your question and add the dataframe and format it as code, so that it is understandable.

Comment: Also, when posting the dataframe be sure to identify the data type of the values, from what I can see you are looking for a string of the form x= 'yellow colored 4', is this correct?

Comment: Tried to make things clearer in my description.  I want the value (int) at **`df[x][y]`** to be styled with the color (string) **`styleList[x][y]`**

Comment: I figured it out—answer added to end of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much prodding of my convoluted solution, I have come to the following (much cleaner) solutions for my original question.

I wasn't able to find these elsewhere on SO, so to anyone else who is interested:

**Solution using `apply(axis=0)`**

```
def f1(col): return [ dfStyle[col.name][i] for i in range(len(dfStyle)) ]

df.style.apply(f1, axis=0)
```

**Solution using `applymap()`** via list comprehension

```
styleIterator = iter([ row for col in dfStyle for row in dfStyle[col] ] )

def f1(x): return next(styleIterator)

df.style.applymap(f1)
```

**Solution using `applymap()`** via built-in functions

```
styleIterator = iter(dfStyle.values.flatten(order='F').tolist() )

# OR

styleIterator = iter(dfStyle.to_numpy().flatten(order='F').tolist() )

def f1(x): return next(styleIterator)

df.style.applymap(f1)
```

and, as provided by a friend, **Solution using `apply(axis=1)`** with lambda

```
color = lambda row: [dfStyle.iloc[row.name][col] for col in dfStyle]

df.style.apply(color, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted at the end of my question, I managed to arrive at my desired solution with:

```
def color(row):
  dfs = dfStyle.copy()
  x = [dfs.iloc[row.name][j] for i,j in zip(row, dfStyle)]
  return x

df.style.apply(color, axis=1)
```

Although this is indeed the solution I was after, it seems like a rather convoluted and unnecessarily complicated way of getting there.

**I would still be grateful to know of a simple and intuitive way to achieve the same.**

[image]